# Bing tag on AMP

Tags: amp-html, bing, bing-ads-api

I have an AMP-based site and I am trying to install Bing Ads Universal Event Tracking on it.

The code I received is:

```
<script>(function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){var o={ti:"TRACKING_ID"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n.async=1,n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){var s=this.readyState;s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)},i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})(window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");</script>
```

I want to know if whether it is possible to add this on an AMP site?

Comment: I'm facing the exact issue. Could you find a solution for it?